# Why do English-speaking children mispronounce “spaghetti” as “pasketti”?

Tags: pronunciation, metathesis

At first glance, this might seem like a very stupid question, and in full honesty, it is. But get this. In Norwegian, *spaghetti* is the same word, and I don't remember ever hearing any child ever say *pasketti*, or similar.

However, Norwegian children are not better. I personally mispronounced Støvler (boots) as Stølver, and Klovn (clown) as Knolv.

I am curious if anyone knows why. I'm guessing there must be an explanation.

Comment: Voted to close because it is opinion based? I disagree with that a lot :)

Comment: Interesting question. It looks like adjacent [metathesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metathesis_(linguistics)). But after that I'm at a loss to say why Norwegian doesn't act in the same way and could only wildly speculate that their is something about the structure of the Norwegian language in general which makes Pasketti as a possible word relatively unlikely as compared to English.

Comment: Even quite a few adults say ***pacific*** instead of ***specific***, presumably because they find that a bit of a tongue-twister. And it's my guess that *most* Anglophones habitually "mispronounce" words like ***Wednesday, February.*** To be honest, I've not noticed any tendency for children in particular to have problems articulating the word ***spaghetti***, but it's nowhere near a "native" English word anyway, so it wouldn't be surprising if they came out with various "Close, but no cigar!" attempts to reproduce it accurately. Any *pacific* reason for the one you've picked out? I doubt it.

Comment: As a none native english speaker (though very fluent) **refridgerator** is the nightmare! I did pick Spaghetti, because there was a joke about it in Modern Family, that went right over my head the first time. And i happened to read a question here that mentioned it again now.

Comment: I know it's compulsory for all children in sitcoms to say "pasketti", but is it really that common in real life? I've only ever heard it on TV.

Comment: I can't remember ever actually hearing *pasketti*, but my nieces said *saghetti* and *sketti* when very young. Less forgivably, I admit to knowing full well the word is *espresso*, yet more than half the time saying *expresso*, ensuring an eye roll from the barista.

Comment: i can confirm that expresso is too common here as well.

Comment: I don’t recall actually hearing _pasketti_ as other than a stylised media pronunciation either, to be honest – I don’t think it’s really that common. Some reduction in a word like _spaghetti_ (which starts with a consonant cluster and has three consecutive plosive with different places of articulation and is thus reasonably complicated for small children) is to be expected, but the particular metathesis in _pasketti_ doesn’t strike me as being especially obvious, compared to so many other incidental metatheses.

Comment: well guys, try doing your research it is a word but you've spelt it wrong. Ask the kids or do a simple web search will turn up some answers for Pasghetti

Comment: One of my children had trouble with "spaghetti" and turned it into "psghetti."  I think initial "sp" is hard for a lot of people in the world, not just children.  Also initial "st."  Most Spanish speakers trip over foreign names and words with initial "sp" and "st." See http://es.namespedia.com/details/Estain (surname "Estain" which is equivalent to our "Stein").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to something called Metathesis.

From Wikipedia on [Metathesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metathesis_(linguistics))

> Metathesis...is the transposition of sounds or syllables in a word or of words in a sentence. Most commonly, it refers to the interchange of two or more contiguous sounds, known as adjacent metathesis or local metathesis.
>
> Metathesis may also involve interchanging non-contiguous sounds...
>
> Metathesis is responsible for some common speech errors, such as children acquiring spaghetti as pasketti. The pronunciation /ˈæsk/ for ask, now considered standard, descends from a northern England version of the verb that in most midland and southern texts through the 1500s was spelled with x or cs, showing pronunciation as /ˈæks/. Chaucer, Caxton, and the Coverdale Bible use ax; Shakespeare and the King James Bible have ask. The word "ask" derives from Proto-Germanic *aiskōną.
>
> Some other frequent English pronunciations that display metathesis are:
>
> - comfortable > comfterble /ˈkʌmftərbəl/
> - nuclear > nucular /ˈnjuːkjʊlər/ (re-analysed as nuke + -cular suffix in molecular,
>     binocular)
> - prescription > perscription /pərˈskrɪpʃən/
>     introduce >
> - interduce /ɪntərˈd(j)uːs/
> - asterisk > asterix /ˈæstərɪks/
> - cavalry > calvary /ˈkælvəri/
> - foliage > foilage /ˈfɔɪlɪdʒ/
> - pretty > purty /ˈpɜːrti/

It is likely that English-speaking children mix up this word more than Norwegian children because of how first language acquisition affects our ability to pronounce words. In English, [here](https://www.dhhs.tas.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0017/25604/cfs_vocab_checklist.pdf) are the words that an English-speaking 2 year old should be able to say. As you can see, the most simple words have consonant-vowel-consonant (CVC), CVCC, or CVVC syllables (dad, mom, ball, door, milk, bad, good). English speaking children, therefore, have an easier time with these syllables than CCV syllables.
Common examples of children altering CCV syllables:

- "spa" > "pas" in spagetti
- "brain" > "bain"
- "specific" > "pacific"
- "library" > "libery"

Comment: I always thought it was methatesis... ;-)

Comment: Metathesis is the name of *what* happened, not *why*. And not even that, if the other answer alleging a pun popularized through media is correct, though it may be a bit of both if the meaningful semantics after the metathesis ease its acceptance. PS: There's a theory of sonority and a sonorant hierarchy, that may explain some learners difficulties; Howevdr, it is just a theory.

Comment: The other examples  show *hapology* which is a bit of a different thing. The ascii transcription does not help, because English spelling is not totally phonetic. That is, I'd transcribe *libwry* and still get it wrong. In fact, the examples don't helö at all, however interesting they are, they rather distract. Just imagine you'd *have to* source these.

Comment: And I think *metathesis* first and foremost describes that two items which changed places have been pronounced literally above each other, that is at nearly the same time, before they diverged. one way or another. Cp e.g. *calvlary*

Comment: Good enough :) !

Answer (score -3):

Why do English speaking children mispronounce *spaghetti* as *pasketti*?

Ha ha this is great reading. Have not had such a laugh in ages. It is not mispronunciation. It's a play on words or was when the FAD started. Oh by the way, **you spelt  Pasketti wrong**

Spaghetti is made from pasta hence the "new" word **pas**ta/spa**ghetti** **pasghetti** sometimes kids can teach us a few things LOL.

[Don't believe me??](https://www.pasghettis.com/menu) Check out the web address. Also check this [pasghetti](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pasghetti)

Comment: I upvoted your answer because these are my thoughts too.

Comment: I downvoted because it is an ad for an Italian restaurant.

Comment: @Mr Lister; Yes correct and the second link is a dictionary which both show the word is in use. It easily search on the net after you switch off the spell checker. Earliest reference I can find is 1984. •  * 1984 Romeo Muller, Puff and the Incredible Mr. Nobody, Troll Communications Llc, p14
"I love pasghetti !" Terry and Nobody sat by the large kitchen window [...]
Which would be about right my Kids were using this term years ago, and my Grand kids are old enough to say it now.